# Purpose of CONSOLE_REAL_OUTPUT_HANDLE macro

Tags: windows, winapi, undocumented-behavior

I read `wincon.h` header and I found two macros:

`CONSOLE_REAL_OUTPUT_HANDLE (LongToHandle(-2))`

`CONSOLE_REAL_INPUT_HANDLE (LongToHandle(-3))`

I've searched across the internet but still didn't find answer.

What's the purpose of those macros? It seems like it's undocumented because I can't find it on MSDN.

Comment: If it's not documented, it's probably not useful. I suppose it's some legacy leftover. Don't bother.

Comment: If I have to throw a wild guess then I'd say they're to obtain the "real" file `HANDLE`s for stdin/stdout without hardcoding those constants ("real" when compared to the input buffer and screen buffers you'd obtain with `GetStdHandle()`). But that's just a guess

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Afaik `STD_XXX_HANDLE` macros are only recognized by ReadFile/WriteFile and GetFileType function. They're treated by them as pseudo-handles

Comment: @Ex-Kyuto Do you mean `GetStdHandle(STD_XXX_HANDLE)`? As far as I can imagine: you can't use them to access the underlying file, that's why I'm guessing these `CONSOLE_REAL_XXX_HANDLE` macros serve that purpose (but again, just a guess)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Surprisingly, you can use `STX_XXX_HANDLE` directly as pseudo file handles.

https://medium.com/@kaw411gh0st/undocumented-behaviour-of-readfile-writefile-618a9994c9cb

Comment: Yeah, those `((DWORD)-1X)` constants were suspicious! Point is: You can `WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ...)` and use ESC codes, for example (which will be stripped off the output file if piped to something which is not a console). If however you `WriteFile()` to those _real_ handles I'd expect them to go through as-is (without being interpreted, even if no redirect is in place). Basically `long` handles 1, 2, and 3 are mapped to `HANDLE` handles -10, -11, -12 Again, just guessing! If you actually try these things out I'd be interested to see the results!

Comment: Just passing `UlongToHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` directly btw, not from return value of `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`. On that articles, I wrote that inside `WriteFile`. `UlongToHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` turns into `NtCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameter->StandardOutput`